# vb.net - does disposing of a form clean up all of its elements?

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, dispose

If I close a form in vb.net by using .dispose(), do I need to worry about cleaning up any of the elements that were created inside the form (like addHandler, etc) or does disposal clean up everything for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing a Form (or calling `Dispose()` on it) will clean up all of the *components* within that form.  This means that any controls added to the form (or its controls, recursively) will automatically clean up.

Event handlers on controls within the form will get cleaned up.

That being said, this will not clean up event handlers which are subscribing to objects not owned by the form.  If you used `AddHandler` to add an event handler to a *type outside of the form*, it would be a good practice to use `RemoveHandler` within an override of [`Form.Dispose(Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka.aspx) to remove this subscription.